# ES6 - Destructuring and For of Loop only returns first object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a react app looping through the following object:

```
const topics = [
  {name: 'Mon', color: 'blue', id: 1},
  {name: 'Tue', color: 'red', id: 2},
  {name: 'Wed', color: 'pink', id: 3},
]
```

I'm trying to destructure and loop through the object via `for of loop` inside my functional component

```
 export const Data = () => {
       for (let {name, color, id} of topics) {
           console.log(name, color, id) //Only first iteration is outputted
               return (
                <div key={id}>
                    <div>{name}</div>
                    <div>{color}</div>
                </div>  
               )                                               
       }
    }
```

I'm only getting `1, Mon, blue`
What am I missing? Is this related to a `return` or `render`?

Comment: You have a `return` statement inside your `for` loop.  That exits the function and thus stops the `for` loop.

Comment: How could I loop and still return/render the all the data as JSX?

Comment: I don't know JSX myself, but here's one idea: [Rendering an Array of Data with map() and JSX](http://www.hackingwithreact.com/read/1/13/rendering-an-array-of-data-with-map-and-jsx) that took me 10 seconds to find with Google.

Comment: That Makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For of Loop only returns first object, Why?

Because you are using return statement inside [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) body, and that is breaking the loop and returning the result. Remove the return and check it will print all the values.

Check this snippet:

```js
const topics = [
  {name: 'Mon', color: 'blue', id: 1},
  {name: 'Tue', color: 'red', id: 2},
  {name: 'Wed', color: 'pink', id: 3},
]


for (let {name, color, id} of topics) {
   console.log(name, color, id);                       
}
```

To render all the data use [#array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, write it like this:

```
export const Data = () => (
    <div>
        {
            topics.map( ({ name, color, id }) => {
                return (
                    <div key={id}>
                        <div>{name}</div>
                        <div>{color}</div>
                    </div>  
                )
            })                                               
        }
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Makes sense, but then I get an error not being able to render the JSX divs on react, how should I re-factor in order to be able to render the data?

Comment: check the updated answer, use map instead of for loop :)

Comment: Thank you so much!! folks are being harsh out here, being downvoted for asking a question? We all start learning somewhere...

Comment: correct, don't hesitate to ask questions, and ignore downvotes :)

Answer (score 3):

In a comment you've asked:

> How could I loop and still return/render the all the data as JSX?

You'd return an array with the elements in it, typically by using `Array#map`:

```
export const Data = () => {
    return topics.map(({name, color, id}) => (
        <div key={id}>
            <div>{name}</div>
            <div>{color}</div>
        </div>  
    ));
};
```

---

Side note: While you can do anything you like in your own code, the *overwhelming* convention in JavaScript is that only constructor functions start with a capital letter. All other functions start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: @TJ Crowder, I am following react's convention: "Always start component names with a capital letter" https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @NullisTrue: I'm not sure `Data` is a component, since it doesn't have a single top-level element (unless you're using v16, which allows an array), and it closes over topics which means it's not self-contained. But again, up to you. :-)